# How can I select row of a given CurrentRegion without using Selection.EntireRow.Select using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can Select a Range, let's say I have a currentRegion between `Range("A3")` to `Range("E3")`

`Range("A3").Select` then continue with `Selection.EntireRow.Select`. But the issue I am facing now is that the later code is taking so much time to run while The range I am only interest into is only the row in the CurrentRegion, that is I want a code would select on from `Range("A3:E3")` basing on my CurrentRegion. I want the code to be dynamic as I am dealing with more than 700 sheets and their respective CurrentRegion will be changing as I loop through the sheets.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the `Intersect` method.

Comment: Thank you all your valuable comments. in Fact, the vba code I am developping intends to copy a row in CurrentRegion of an ActiveSheet. The same row will be determined after finding out the whole currentRegion basing on provided identifier. After finding the location range of that identifier, the code will copy the whole range within CurrentRegion and paste it into another workbook.

Comment: Assuming you wish to select "CurrentRegion" named range instead of selecting whole row then try this command -> Range("CurrentRegion").Select & iterate through the selection...

Comment: There are several ways how to do it. If you could share your code, surely an efficient one would be presented, primarily without using `Select` or `Activate`. Without the code or at least a screenshot of your data and more detail, one can't be sure what to do.